# Ordering using a declared variable's property

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

I have a `ScInfo` class that exists in many different classes. This class also has a list of `ScDetails` which has a `Date` member variable called `nextExecution`.

I need to continuously look up eligible objects with their `ScDetails` object's `nextExecution` member variable is after or equal to the current server's time (i.e. **persistenceManagerInstance.getServerDate()**). Meaning that I need to look up objects, with `ScInfo` having a `ScDetails` object with `nextExecution` >= serverDate)

So I use the following method (A portion is shown):

```
public List<Object[]> getEligbleForExecution(long amount) {
    PersistenceManager pm = null;
    Transaction t = null;
    try {
        pm = getPM();
        t = pm.currentTransaction();
        t.begin();
        Query q = pm
                .newQuery(
                        entityClass, //This is generic
                        "!this.deleted && this.scheduleActive && det.active == true && (det.nextExecution == null || det.nextExecution <= :serverDate) && det.running == false && this.scInfo.scDetails.contains(det)");
        q.declareVariables(ScDetail.class.getName() + " det;");
        q.setRange(0, amount);
        q.setResult("this, det");
        q.setOrdering("det.nextExecution"); // This is the statement I need to apply but it's causing the error below
        Date serverDate = pm.getServerDate();
        List<Object[]> raw = new ArrayList<Object[]>((List<Object[]>) q.execute(serverDate));
```

Which throws the following error stack trace (**DEBUG** level, I mentioned what I thought to be essential for solving this problem):

```
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] >> QueryToSQL.processVariable (unbound) variable=det is not yet bound so returning UnboundExpression
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Updating mapping of org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.NullLiteral@727f3b8a to be org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.DateMapping@e72a8082
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Transaction rolling back for ObjectManager org.datanucleus.MultithreadedObjectManager@fba0f36
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Rolling back [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid={A strange uncopyable character is in here !}, enlisted resources=[]]
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Transaction rolled back in 1 ms
14:54:32 ERROR (ScTasksDAOImpl.java:67)-[main] Looking up eligible SC tasks
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.processVariableExpression(QueryToSQLMapper.java:3245)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.processPrimaryExpression(QueryToSQLMapper.java:2075)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compilePrimaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:180)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileUnaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:169)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileAdditiveMultiplicativeExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:148)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileRelationalExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:123)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileOrAndExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:46)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:337)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.compileOrdering(QueryToSQLMapper.java:845)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.QueryToSQLMapper.compile(QueryToSQLMapper.java:403)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JDOQLQuery.java:883)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileInternal(JDOQLQuery.java:343)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1747)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1666)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:243)
    at com.sc.ipk.sc.services.ScTasksDAOImpl.getEligbleForExecution(ScTasksDAOImpl.java:41)
    at com.sc.ipk.ixl.services.IxlTestDAOImpl.main(IxlTestDAOImpl.java:977)
14:54:32 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Object Manager "org.datanucleus.MultithreadedObjectManager@fba0f36" closed
```

So is it not possible to use declared variables to query ordering ? I tried using sub-queries but I couldn't get that to work either, may be I can start a new question for that, if ordering using declared variables isn't possible.

**EDIT:**
Neil generously suggested that ordering based on an element that should exist in a collection doesn't look reasonable to him. I understand that but I cannot for example look-up `ScDetails` objects first after ordering them of course and then look-up my main objects afterwards because my target main object may differ from time to time and I may look-up `ScDetails` objects that doesn't belong to the main candidate class.

For example:
**A** has `ScInfo` which has a collection of `ScDetails`
**B**, **C** (Same as above)

So if I lookup `ScDetails` objects first (After ordering an all), I cannot filter my main candidate classes (**A**, **B** & **C**) because I may use a `ScDetails` that belongs to **A** while I'm trying to get **B** or **C** candidates.

Thank you.

Comment: No idea whether its "allowed" or not, but your query structure is weird. Would be better to put "this.scInfo.scDetails.contains(det)" at the start, since that introduces the "det" variable, rather than expecting some query parser to search all the way to the end to find out what it is

Comment: @NeilStockton, I tried what you suggested but it gave the same result. I'm wondering if it's a matter of ORM, may be the objects should be related in a specific way that allows this query ? Also if you find my query "weird", what should I read to know how to make a "good" JDO query ?
`JDO` answers are very scarce here so thanks a lot, your feedback is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can order by *that* variable. It represents an element of a collection of the candidate. Consequently if a candidate has say 5 elements then it is indeterminate how it can order by some property on the element (1-N mapping). Obviously if the candidate was the element then ordering by some property of the element makes perfect sense, whether variable or not.

Comment: `Obviously if the candidate was the element..`: I'm not sure what do you mean by `Candidate` but I think you mean `The returned value` ? I've already specified the `det` object as a return in the results (i.e. q.setResult(`this, det`)) along with the the owning object (i.e. Object owning `ScInfo`, that owns `ScDetails` that owns a collection of the `det` object). Regards

Comment: The candidate is what the JDO spec calls the persistable class being selected (aka "this"). You're ordering by something that is not 1-1 with "this", therefore it doesn't make sense (to me). Also returning a variable as a result alongside "this" also doesn't make sense (to me) since it is also not single-valued with respect to "this".

Comment: I can fully understand if ordering by a collection variable doesn't sound reasonable, and I guess this is the key to at least resolve this situation for now. But returning this variable as a results alongside `this` is actually reasonable as each row will be treated differently.  Each result row (this-det) will be processed based on data in the `det` object. Although `this` will exist in more than one instance, it's important that it exists with each `det` object separately in the result. Or may be I need to redesign my processors.